# Direct memory access, using pointer to the address

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-address

I was playing with **C++ pointers**, i have a doubt, is it possible that i check the **memory address** of a variable from a program and store that address in a pointer of another program and output the value stored at that location.

Program 1:

```
int t1 = 34;
int t2 = 0;

std::cout << &t1;
std::cin>>t2;
```

This is the first program, i input the **address of t1** in the second program, outputted by the **cout**.

Program 2:

```
 int* t3 = (int*)address_of_t1 // address of t1 is not a function....it will be replaced by the address returned by first program
 int out = *t3;
 cout <<out;
```

I run the first program and let it wait for input, keep it running..
Then simultaneously i run the second program, but the second program always output `0`, it never shows the value of `t1` from first program.

Comment: If you are running this on a modern OS, then by default the memory spaces of two unrelated processes are disjoint.

Comment: The term "Direct Memory Access" is a bit unfortunate as that has a [special meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on a modern operating system. Memory is virtual, meaning that that you can have the same address in two different processes mapped to completely different physical memory locations.
See more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory.

Comment: Not impossible. Just requires some OS specific calls and process setup.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

The addresses you get in a single process are unique for that particular process. All modern operating systems allocate a virtual memory address space to run the executable code.